# How is the whole thing working?

Tags: java, jsp, struts

when learning to write basic application using struts i came across the following code which works fine.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>detail</param-name>
        <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**index.jsp**

```
jsp:forward page="HelloWorld.do"/>
```

**struts-config.xml**

```
<struts-config>

<form-beans>
<form-bean name="HelloWorldActionForm"
```

type="com.vaannila.HelloWorldActionForm"/>

```
<action-mappings>
<action input="/index.jsp" name="HelloWorldActionForm" path="/HelloWorld" scope="session" type="com.vaannila.HelloWorldAction">
<forward name="success" path="/helloWorld.jsp" />
</action>
</action-mappings>
```

**HelloWorldActionForm**

```
public class HelloWorldActionForm extends
org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm {

private String message;

public String getMessage() {
  return message;
}

public void setMessage(String Message) {
   message = Message;
}

}
```

**HelloWorldAction.java**

```
public class HelloWorldAction extends org.apache.struts.action.Action {

private final static String SUCCESS = "success";

public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,
HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

HelloWorldActionForm helloWorldForm = (HelloWorldActionForm) form;
helloWorldForm.setMessage("Hello World!");
return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
 }
}
```

**helloWorld.jsp**

```
Hey ! It's me from struts.
```

The application works fine . But i don't understand how does request `HelloWorld.do` finally reach `helloWorld.jsp` after i had opened `index.jsp` ? I do understand the thing that `HelloWorldAction` actually returns the page .

Comment: Here is how the flow goes: When you access index.jsp, the request is forwarded to HelloWorld.do (refer jsp:forward). The app server on seeing the .do pattern, passes the request to ActionServlet (refer: web.xml). Now the ActionServlet has been configured with the struts-config.xml file. The config file has an action defined for /HelloWorld. Hence the request is processed by HelloWorldAction and it returns 'success' code - which is mapped to helloWorld.jsp (again refer to struts-config.xml) which is the 'view' that is returned by the ActionServlet 'controller'. Hope that helps.

Comment: You should have put this down as an answer :)

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/docs/the-struts-2-request-flow.html

Comment: If you are just learning... don't use struts1, use struts2.

Comment: @ ben in the tag `<action input="/index.jsp" name="HelloWorldActionForm" path="/HelloWorld" scope="session" type="com.vaannila.HelloWorldAction">` what does name attribute tell ?

Comment: @ ben can you explain this `Now the ActionServlet has been configured with the struts-config.xml file. `

Answer (score 0):

When your **HelloWorldAction.execute** returns (effective a string) **"success"**

THEN

```
<forward name="success" path="/helloWorld.jsp" />
```

matches **"success"** and delivers **"/helloWorld.jsp"**

Comment: in the tag `<action input="/index.jsp" name="HelloWorldActionForm" path="/HelloWorld" scope="session" type="com.vaannila.HelloWorldAction">` what does _name_ attribute tell ?